# Is there a way to get Adapter position and index of child within "onDetachedFromWindow"?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am implementing exoplayer  in recyclerView in a way which stops other videos from playing when they are not in the window ,this requires me to set the stop and start command within onDetached from window using an "if" statement,this method is only workable when am able to get the "AdapterPosition" and "indexOfChild"....i have checked through  stackoverflow for another solution but most solutions aren't very clear on the implementation but i just need help on how i can get the adapterPosition and indexofchild within "onDetachedWindow" to control the plabackState of exoplayer

below is some code from my ViewHolder to give an easy explanation on how i want to control playback state in "onDetachedWindow":

```
 class VideoViewPagerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CircleImageView profile;
    StyledPlayerView playerView;
    TextView userName;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    int videoSurfaceDefaultHeight=0;
    int screenDefaultHeight=0;

    public VideoViewPagerViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        profile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        playerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);


    }

    public void setData(Detail data, Integer position, SparseArray<String> storedMedia, SparseArray<ExoPlayer> storedPlayer, SparseArray<StyledPlayerView> playerView) {

        storedMedia.append(position, data.getVideo());
        storedPlayer.append(position, getVideoPlayer(itemView.getContext()));
        playerView.append(position,getVideosource(itemView.getContext()));
    }

    private StyledPlayerView getVideosource(Context context) {
        WindowManager wm=(WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display=wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size=new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        videoSurfaceDefaultHeight= size.x;
        screenDefaultHeight=size.y;
        playerView= new StyledPlayerView(context);

        playerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM);
        playerView.setUseController(false);
        playerView.setShowBuffering(StyledPlayerView.SHOW_BUFFERING_WHEN_PLAYING);

        return playerView;
    }


    private ExoPlayer getVideoPlayer(Context context) {

        ExoPlayer  player= new ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();

        return player;

    }
}
```

Comment: does your StyledPlayerView is repeated in each item view?

Comment: Before I implemented the code it was somehow using the same for all the views created with videos... because when I tried to implement "onDetached," and "on attached" the behavior affected all the views ...when I told it to stop "StylePlayerView" onDetached.... every view I slides passed the viewpager would stop working unless the unslided views

Comment: where do you set data and bind ViewHoleder?

Comment: Previously I was setting data in the "onBind" that's where I use to place all commands of the exoplayer and other information like for images and so on

Comment: It works fine but the shortcome of that approach is that u have difficulty to stop other views from playing videos when your not on the specific view